# why glassfish crashs randomely

Tags: windows, memory, java, dump, minidumps

I'm using oracle-glassfish3.1.2 on java 1.7 (I know these technology is a little dated) , when I start the server I use the verbose option: asadmin start-domain --verbose;

I've also used asadmin to create a service, so glassfish run as a windows service;

Sometimes the server crashs, and I have checked on windows log and I saw there is a memory.hdmp and also WERE554.tmp.mdmp, I've open memory.hdmp using windbg and i can see:

```
    CONTEXT: (.ecxr) rax=00000000019f88d0 rbx=0000000000be5710 rcx=00000000019fc000 rdx=000000002f532501 rsi=000000001a91ec10 rdi=0000000000be5710 rip=00007ffbb97a49b9 rsp=000000001a91eae0 rbp=0000000080070020 r8=0000000000000001 r9=00000000019f8948 r10=00000000019fc078 r11=0000000000000000 r12=00000000e0434f4d r13=ffffffff80070020 r14=0000000000000001 r15=0000000000000001 iopl=0 nv up ei pl nz na pe nc cs=0033 ss=002b ds=002b es=002b fs=0053 gs=002b efl=00000202 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x69: 00007ffb`b97a49b9 0f1f440000 nop dword ptr [rax+rax] Resetting default scope

EXCEPTION_RECORD: (.exr -1) ExceptionAddress: 00007ffbb97a49b9 (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x0000000000000069) ExceptionCode: e0434f4d (CLR exception) ExceptionFlags: 00000001 NumberParameters: 1 Parameter[0]: ffffffff80070020

PROCESS_NAME: DRM-domain1-GlassFishService.exe

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR: 80070020

FAULTING_THREAD: ffffffff

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT: SOS.DLL is not loaded for managed code. Analysis might be incomplete

STACK_TEXT: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 DRM_domain1_GlassFishService!unknown_function+0x0

STACK_COMMAND: ** Pseudo Context ** ManagedPseudo ** Value: ffffffff ** ; kb

SYMBOL_NAME: DRM_domain1_GlassFishService!unknown_function

MODULE_NAME: DRM_domain1_GlassFishService

IMAGE_NAME: DRM-domain1-GlassFishService.exe

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: CLR_EXCEPTION_NOSOS_80070020_DRM-domain1-GlassFishService.exe!unknown_function

OS_VERSION: 10.0.17763.1

BUILDLAB_STR: rs5_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE: x64

OSNAME: Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION: 1.0.0.0

FAILURE_ID_HASH: {e954e680-c7c8-cf1b-b47d-5ee0880932f0}
```

But these information are unuseful to me, is there a way to understand what is the meaning? In particular what is the meaning of ExceptionCode: e0434f4d, and what can I do to solve the issue?

In other words, how I can investigate further the issue? Any help is really appreciated, I have googled but wasn't able to find out any usuful tip;

On application log and also on glassfish log, there is no error neither exception that let me to say a memory leak or something similar.

Comment: Error 0x80070020 means that the process can't access the file because it's being used by another process. Try to find more information about the problem file, also in the Event Viewer.

Comment: @harrymc thx, it should means that my glassfish application use some file (I think some dll file), that are used by other process, that cannot be access; If so you suggest to look for the file in the event viewer but what I have to check in the event viewer? for example a warning that decribes something like (the file cannot be access). thx so much

Comment: Searching the Event Viewer is not that simple and is somewhat a matter of luck. If you can enable logging in glassfish or java it would also perhaps give additional information. I don't use glassfish myself, so cannot help here except with generalities.

Comment: thx, just onther question (if you can answer), is there a place that can allow me to dimostrate that error code 0x80070020 means what you have indicated? may be a catalog on windows error. thx

Comment: No, I don't know of any such thing. You/us need more information to form an opinion.